# How to create an .swf file that will simply load a webpage in an iFrame once opened?

Tags: actionscript-3, iframe, flash

I am very new to flash and actionscript. I simply would like to know is it possible and then what is the code needed to create a simple .swf file that once double-clicked on opens and all it has inside it's window is an iframed website (scrolling and resizing are optional), basically a simple flash mini-browser if you will, with no navigation features of any kind just the ability to click inside and maybe refresh the page...

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why flash mini-browser, why not browser mini-window?

Comment: It's a little experiment I'm doing, it has to be .swf file with a website in it - is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with a website inside a website, which is what `<iframe>` was designed for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there some way to show HTML content inside Flash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909/is-there-some-way-to-show-html-content-inside-flash)

Answer (score 2):

Try **flashQuery** - it supports tags inside flash http://flashquery.org/documentation/overview

Comment: The link is dead, but still in the archives: https://web.archive.org/web/20110707053826/http://flashquery.org/

Comment: Does anyone have a copy of flashquery? archive.org didn't cache any of the downloads and I'd like to study it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even try it!

This question is probably a duplicate of - [Is there some way to show HTML content inside Flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909/is-there-some-way-to-show-html-content-inside-flash)

Also you should read this about parsing HTML - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Also, Flash does not have "iframes". They are a browser thing!